# Why do people speak as though "all" does not imply "some"?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, introduction-to-philosophy, quantification

Suppose someone asks whether some of the people in a classroom are over 20 years old, and then someone says, "No, all of the people are". Why would they say that? Why can't they say something like, "Yes, and in fact all of the people are"? Basically, my question is, why do a lot of people frequently speak as though "all" does not imply "some"? And have philosophers talked about this point of language?

Comment: I am not sure what this has to do with philosophy. You obviously have figured out what the correct answer in terms of logical implications would be. And yes, normal people speaking normal language are usually bad at logic if one does analyse set theoretical propositions and responses. What is the philosophical point here?

Comment: The TLDR is that there can be disagreements on when to use "all" and "some" by people who value different goals in communication.

Comment: Your example of accepting that it is OK to say, "Yes, and in fact all..." does not show that 'all' implies 'some' - it shows that 'all' is *consistent* with 'some'. "All Fs are Gs" does not exclude "some Fs are Gs" from being true". It is much more controversial to claim that 'all' *implies* 'some' and this typically does not hold when we allow for the possibility of there being no Fs.

Comment: To elaborate on Bumble’s response: suppose you’re looking into an empty room through a window. So, by the principle of explosion you can truly conclude that “everyone in that room is over 20” as well as “everyone in that room is 20 or younger”. The same holds for “the present King of France”; since there is none, whoever it is must be bald, and whoever it is must not be bald.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the philosophy of language, the motivation of speakers is relevant to the Wittgensteinian notion of the [language game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_game_(philosophy)). In [*Philosophical Investigations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Investigations), late LW talks about how the meaning of words themselves are a function of the aims of the [agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agency_(philosophy)). It turns out, that meanings of words can be viewed as [conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_(norm)) rather than objective facts, and that the [normativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity) that inheres to words provides fertile grounds for speakers of a language to compete in order to get what they want. A classic example of how people struggle politically over language is relying on [prestige dialects and languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_(sociolinguistics)). The same can be true for interpreting what are known as logical meanings. Consider the case of two lawyers who are debating over whether a subject on the stand meant to use inclusive or [exclusive disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). Whether an 'or' in a deposition is meant to be "either one or the other" or "one, the other, or both" might be enough to turn the entire case in the direction of a one decision or another.

So, if one is talking about does 'all' imply 'some' and does 'some' imply 'all', then one has to understand why two groups of people might see the relationship differently. If there is a discrepancy between two groups that doesn't involve political motivation writ large, then it may be that one group uses an intuitive or folk definition and another uses a technical definition.  Another example are the many forms of logical implication that are conveyed by use of the [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional), [strict conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_conditional), or other interpretations of 'if'. From the article on material conditional:

> Due to the paradoxes of material implication and related problems, material implication is not generally considered a viable analysis of conditional sentences in natural language.

Thus, someone with logical training may use 'if' in one way, a way distinct from your kindly, unschooled grandma who perfectly confirmed your intuition of using if another way.

Lastly, there are a variety of logics that can be employed when using words that depend on acceptance of various assumptions. A [multivalued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic) might be employed to relate two words using truthyness instead of strict notions of truth and falsity that rely on [the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle). Thus, the relationship between two terms like 'all' and 'some' might have alternative interpretations.

Now to your example. If in a classroom where 25 of 25 people are over the age of 20, clearly the [existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) of some people being over 20 can be established by a single sample. If 1 of 25 ages are inspected one can say with certainty and accuracy that some of the people in the room are over the age of 20. If every age is determined, in this case 25 of 25 being older than 20, then and only then can one say with certainty that [universally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), all students are older than 20.

Now, after this point, someone says, "some" and someone corrects by saying "all", then the motivation, which is open to speculation, might be to maintain a precise accounting of facts, for in fact, universal quantification is known to apply since there is no uncertainty about the age of everyone in the population. Is this correction necessary? Perhaps if one is doing statistics and there is a difference in methods that need to be applied. Talking about samples and populations is a different subject, and that sort of precision might be applied. However, there is a less rational reason that might obtain, and that is that some people are inveterate "correctors" who habitually assume the mantle of correcting others' mistakes or inaccuracies. I myself suffer from the disposition of the latter.

What is important here is that there are two distinct ways to approach language use and evaluation, one is descriptivist, that is, it seeks only to account for why it is done and what is done and, and the other is prescriptivist, which seeks to direct the behavior of others often with a rationale accounting for why it should be done. We are all subject to forces of [language prescription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) either through informal pressure to conform or explicit pressure such as in education or adherence to formal standards, say, to send a business letter or publish a research paper. There are two tensions that apply between the sloppy or creative use of language and the attempt to keep it standardized to be useful. Ultimately, living languages ultimately change, and there are always psychological and social forces that clash to try to maintain an equilibrium.

Ultimately, however, individual motivations are an empirical question.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a linguistic nuance than a logical one.

More specifically, "some" in non-logical contexts is generally understood to mean "some, but not all"; to avoid this, you can say "at least some" instead.

Also, though, from a purely linguistic standpoint the respondent can also just omit the "yes" or "no" entirely, and be understood to have answered your question with just "they all are".